# Is $(x^2 - x + yz)$ a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Is $(x^2 - x + yz)$ a prime ideal in $\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$?

I have been trying to prove that it is.

My first approach was to try to show that $f(x,y,z) = x^2 - x + yz$ is irreducible but I wasn't able to do it.

I also tried to show that $\frac{\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]}{(x^2 - x + yz)}$ is an integral domain, but I don't know what the quotient ring looks like so that didn't help either.

Comment: To show irreducible consider for $f=gh$ the degree in X, i.e. $deg_X(f)=deg_X(g)+deg_X(h)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose towards a contradiction that $f=x^2-x+yz$ is reducible. Then there exist nonconstant $g,h\in\Bbb{C}[x,y,z]$ such that $f=gh$. Comparing degrees shows that
$$\deg_zg+\deg_zh=\deg_zgh=\deg_zf=1,$$
so without loss of generality $g=uz+v$ with $u,v\in\Bbb{C}[x,y]$ and $h\in\Bbb{C}[x,y]$. We see that
$$x^2-x+yz=f=gh=uhz+vh,$$
which shows that $uh=y$ and $vh=x^2-x$. In particular $h$ divides both $y$ and $x^2-x$, contradicting our assumption that $h$ is nonconstant. Hence $f$ is irreducible.

---

Analogous arguments work when comparing the degrees in $x$ or $y$, or the total degrees; try them all out.